# kettle Loading transformation from XML file [null]

Tags: xml, transformation, kettle

i am ready to use kettle api to execute a job dynamically.In the process,i need to load transformation from XML file.
question: load transformation from XML file [null]

codes:

```
KettleEnvironment.init();
JobMeta jobMeta = new JobMeta();
jobMeta.setName("jobMeta");
int x=50,y =50;

JobEntryCopy startCopy = JobMeta.createStartEntry();
startCopy.setLocation(x, y);
startCopy.setDrawn();
jobMeta.addJobEntry(startCopy);
JobEntryCopy lastCopy = startCopy;

JobEntryTrans jobEntryTrans = new JobEntryTrans("transData.ktr");


jobEntryTrans.setSpecificationMethod(
    ObjectLocationSpecificationMethod.FILENAME);
JobEntryCopy transCopy = new JobEntryCopy(jobEntryTrans);
transCopy.setName("Execute" + GlobalMethodAndParams.TRANS_NAME);
transCopy.setDrawn();
jobMeta.addJobEntry(transCopy);
JobHopMeta transHop = new JobHopMeta(lastCopy,transCopy);
jobMeta.addJobHop(transHop);
lastCopy = transCopy;

Job job = new Job(null,jobMeta);
job.start();
job.waitUntilFinished();
```

thanks

Comment: Urgent task ,thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `transData.ktr` is in the current directory?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
JobEntryTrans jobEntryTrans = new JobEntryTrans("transData.ktr");
```

most probably means "**File transData.ktr in directory in which jvm was launched**". At least try absolute file path.